# Are there podcasts or blogs focused on the Dresden RPG?

Tags: dresden-files, podcast

I'm thinking about starting up a campaign using Dresden Files RPG.  I have read the novels and both rules books, but I've never really seen the game played.  I'm hoping to find some podcasts or blogs that discuss the game in more detail.  A podcast of live play sessions would be ideal.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Knights of the Night](http://kotnpodcast.blogspot.com/) normally play WoD, but they have a significant collection of podcasts that catalog their [two Dresden campaigns](http://kotnpodcast.blogspot.com/p/dresden-rpg.html).  They run a nice balance between role playing and explaining mechanics to their listeners, and the shows are pretty well edited.

Comment: I've listened to a couple of KotN's DF play podcasts, and they're quite helpful as a GM who is having trouble visualizing what the game looks like at the table.

Answer (score 10):

I found [Rick Neal's set of blogs about DFRPG](http://www.rickneal.ca/?page_id=842) to be enlightening and instructive. He also has a few [playtest](http://www.rickneal.ca/?page_id=13) sessions ( an early version of the game, however).

Comment: Rick Neal's series on Evocation and Thaumaturgy are *excellent*, and I recommend his posts on the non-magic stuff even to players of non-DFRPG Fate games.

Answer (score 4):

A good podcast of sessions (with an interview afterwards with Jim Butcher) were run by the people over at [The Walking Eye](http://www.thewalkingeye.com/?cat=599).  [Fandible](http://www.fandible.com/tag/dresden-files-2/) has a longer running campaign of The Dresden Files, and the thing I like about it is seeing the evolution of their games over time as they gain a better grasp on the rules and how to use the storytelling tools.

Answer (score 4):

My group started recording a Dresden Files FATE rpg campaign about 6 months ago. You can check it out here:

http://burneverythinggaming.podbean.com/category/moonbucks/

We would love to get some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

@ladenedge's suggestion of Knights of the Night is excellent.  I also found another decent set of podcasts from [Actual People Actual Play](http://spookyouthouse.com/sop/index.php?/shows/show/53).  If you look through their back episodes, many of them are focused on Dresden.  Ironically, they don't record the actual play sessions, but give good commentary on the game and how to effectively run it.

Comment: I'm getting 404's on the Dresden eps. Do you know if the back catalog is mirrored anywhere ?

Comment: No I don't sorry.  I was able to download them when I tried a couple months ago.